# wp-parallax-content-slider plugin placing in one page only

Tags: plugins

I am new to wordpress, I have installed the parallax content slider in my demo site. Now the site consists for 5 static pages and I want the slider to appear only on the first page.

If I add the function in the header.php its shown in all the pages.

if ( function_exists( 'get_wp_parallax_content_slider' ) ) {
get_wp_parallax_content_slider();
}

If I add the short code
[parallaxcontentslider]
above the page it doesn't look good as the format of my home page is
1. header with navigation
2. the slider.
3. accordian.
4. testimonials.
5. the static page.